# Missing Column results (Should be easy fix)

Tags: sql, postgresql

For some reason this only returns the correct corresponding city and count to the country but refuses to return the country column. The second and third columns are returning shifted to left by one. The results are correct, it's just when I call SELECT country.name, this field is not being returned.

```
SELECT
  country.name,
  city.name,
  COUNT(country_language.language) AS count
FROM
  lab6.country,
  lab6.city,
  lab6.country_language
GROUP BY
  country.name,
  country.country_code,
  country_language.country_code,
  city.name,
  city.id
HAVING
  COUNT(country_language.language) >= 8 AND
  COUNT(country_language.language) <= 12 AND
  country.country_code = country_language.country_code AND
  country.capital = city.id
```

Comment: Wild guess, you're using `mysql`?

Comment: And it allows you to `SELECT` columns in your `GROUP BY` which don't appear in your `SELECT` column list??

Comment: I'm not sure. Everything I had in GROUP BY was because it threw an error telling me to when I ran the query.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO which column are you referring to?

Comment: @user3396915 use `SELECT country.name AS country_name, city.name AS city_name, ...` The two identical aliases (`name`) are confusing your (PHP?) application.

Comment: How do I give you a correct answer for a comment? xD

Answer (score 1):

You most likely need to alias one of the name columns, like so:

```
SELECT
  country.name,
  city.name as city_name,
  COUNT(country_language.language) AS count
  ...
```